# Как можно получить instance Exception по классу

Tags: java, исключения

Добрый день!

Подскажите, плиз.
Имеется следующий класс:

```
public class ValidationException extends RuntimeException {
    public ValidationException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public ValidationException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

//    public static ValidationException getInstance(String message) {
//        return new ValidationException(message);
//    }
//
//    public static ValidationException getInstance(String message, Throwable cause) {
//        return new ValidationException(message, cause);
//    }

}
```

У него есть несколько наследников. В метод приходит класс эксцепшна

```
Class<? extends ValidationException>
```

Есть-ли какой-то красивый способ получения инстанцов этих классов, без определения статических методов getInstance() (закоментированы) в каждом из наследников?

Comment: `new ValidationExceptionOne(...)`, `new ValidationExceptionTwo(...)`

Comment: У меня есть параметр Class<? extends ValidationExeption> clazz
Надо экцепшн кинуть по этому clazz

Comment: Не понимаю фразу "Надо экцепшн кинуть по этому clazz". Может быть это что-то специфическое "джавское"?

Comment: Igor, Т.е. есть объект: Class<? extends Validation> clazz
Хочу получить инстанс этого класса. 

Этого можно добиться определив закоментированные методы getInstance() в этом классе и в каждом из потомков. Но ищу более красивое решение.

Comment: ну есть еще рефлексия, если вас это устроит. у объекта вызываете .getClass().newInstance()

Comment: К сожалению, newInstance работает без параметров, а у Exception нет сеттеров на message и cause. Разве только сделать их полями в моем классе и объявить геттеры/сеттеры.
PS Похоже решил свой вопрос по другому, вообще без создания наследников у ValidationException.

Comment: ну так вы полезли в рефлексию для создания экземпляра класса, что в таком случае мешает добраться с помощью той же рефлексии до приватного поля?